# Is it possible to pass data from app to a web form using webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to use Javascript injection via my mobile app to pass data from the app to fields of my webview. I have a website form that has fields such as name, email, ect. The name and email and all other information is in my native mobile application. I would like to pass that relative information to the respective web form fields. Is this possible? Below is what I have tried.

```
        wv = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.wv_help);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // do nothing
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                // do nothing
            }

            @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, @NonNull WebResourceRequest req, @NonNull WebResourceError err) {
                // do nothing
            }
        });

        String htmlValue = "<html xmlns=\"https://my_web_form.com\"><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"><title>Lorem Ipsum</title></head><body style=\"width:300px; color: #00000; \"><p><strong> About us</strong> </p><p><strong> Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text</p></body></html>";
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://my_web_form.com", htmlValue, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", "");
```

The result of the above code is a blank screen with the meta data. I want to be able to add the meta data text to specific fields on my web form.

Comment: If you are going to downvote, explain your reasoning. The question I have asked is legitimate and follows SO rules/standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView have `postUrl` function.

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
String url = "http://www.example.com";
String postData = "Your Post data here";
webview.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes());
```

Comment: if I have a form with first name, last name for example. How does post URL allow me to populate that form by passing data from my mobile app, to those relative fields. Understand that this is not a web app. It is a native application using a webview.

Comment: Like this
`String postData = "firstname=" + URLEncoder.encode(my_firstname, "UTF-8") + "&lastname=" + URLEncoder.encode(lastname, "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible by using postUrl function.